# c# WPF Window doesn't show during While Loop. UDP

Tags: c#, wpf, udp

I am new to C# and trying a UDP reader.  I am sending continuous 'Test' text message every second.  However the Main Window and tex box doesn't appear at all.  I notice this always happens when I introduce a while loop.    Without the while loop the window/textbox appears and writes the incoming message 'text' once.  I have a seperate program continuously sending the UDP message.

I m stuck here.  The code with while loops works ok in a console.

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            bool done = false;
            var receivePort = 11000;

            InitializeComponent();

            UdpClient readerClient = new UdpClient(receivePort);


            while (!done)
            {

                var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, receivePort);

                byte[] bytesReceived = readerClient.Receive(ref remoteEP);

                tb.AppendText(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The updates to redraw controls is done via messages. These messages must be processed (it happens on the background). The problem you're facing is that these messages aren't handled due to the while loop. The whileloop/Receive blocks the current thread.

The best thing you should do, is move the UDP code to a separate thread/task.

You could try something like this.

Here is an example using a separate thread:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private UdpClient _readerClient;
    private Thread _udpThread;
    private ManualResetEvent _done = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private int _receivePort;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        _receivePort = 11000;

        InitializeComponent();

        _readerClient = new UdpClient(_receivePort);

        _udpThread = new Thread(UDPHandler);
    }


    private void UDPHandler()
    {

        while (!_done.WaitOne(0))
        {

            var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _receivePort);

            byte[] bytesReceived = _readerClient.Receive(ref remoteEP);

            // since this is (probably) NOT the UI thread, post it to it's dispatcher. (WPF)
            // this makes multithreading harder...
            tb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                tb.AppendText(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived));
            }));

        }
    }

    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // stop the while loop
        _done.Set();
        // wait until the thread finished.
        _udpThread.Join();
    }
}
```

You should add some exception handling etc.. it's just an example..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you are using and blocking the main thread that also WPF wants to use for painting its elements.

So WPF has to wait until your loop finishes.

What C# offers is async/await
(untested)

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // async Task is important here
        public async Task DoStuffAsync()
        {
            bool done = false;
            var receivePort = 11000;
            
            UdpClient readerClient = new UdpClient(receivePort);
            var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, receivePort);
            readerClient.Connect(remoteEP);

            while (!done)
            {
                // Here we await the result
                // meanwhile the main thread is not blocked and WPF can do its work
                // look for ...Async functions in your modules that provide awaitable functionality
                byte[] bytesReceived = await readerClient.ReceiveAsync();

                tb.AppendText(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived));

            }
        }
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Here we call an async function.
            // Problem here: You cannot catch exceptions, because of asyncs nature
            // But you can set code that is executed when the async function fails
            DoStuffAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                // Exception is in t.Exception
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This example is designed to have as few changes as possible not to be best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. I still struggled to get this working but had to study quite a bit. I'm not sure if this is best practice code but works for my personal project.  I still have all the exemptions do to but delighted as I was close to giving up!

```
    public partial class pUDP : Page
{
    public pUDP()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        
    }

    private async void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var port = 11000;
        bool done = false;
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(port);

        IPEndPoint listenEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);


        while (!done)
            {
             
                byte[] receivedData = await Task.Run(() => listener.Receive(ref listenEndPoint));
                tbRead.AppendText(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedData));                  

            }

        listener.Close();


    }
}
```

}

Comment: You will have a problem when an exception happens on listener.Receive().